# Python 3, Tkinter Frame destruction

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
def _on_plant_name_text_entry_changed(p_event):
    frame = Frame(root, width=190, height=200,borderwidth=2, relief=RAISED)
    
    frame.place(x=275,y=35)
    plant_list_box_populate(plant_ent_txt_var.get())
    
    if len(plant_ent_txt_var.get()) == 0:
        print("should work")
        frame.destroy()
        root.update()
```

The method above fires every time the entry widget's input is changed. For some reason the frame does not get destroyed and is still visible in the root window even though the lines get executed. Is there anything obvious that I'm omitting ?

Thank you

Comment: If the conditions match it will destroy the frame that was just created, but not all of the Frames that were created previously when the conditions did not match. What is the end goal here? Just show a box while there is text in the Entry? Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: On every change in the Entry widget input, the method above gets called. Within the plant_list_box_populate() method is called which basically fetches entries in a database based on what can be matched from the input. A frame containing a listbox is created into which the results are populated. That all works fine, the problem is mainly with destroying that single frame which is created within the same function. I know the condition is met, as the print statement gets executed.

Comment: So you type "a". A Frame is created. Then you delete the "a". A second frame is created, the condition is met, the program prints "should work" and the second frame is destroyed. What about the first Frame? It's still there. We can solve this, but I suspect this is an XY problem so I want you to tell me the big picture and provide an [mcve] first.

Comment: It was indeed that simple, a new frame was being created on each call. I feel dumb for missing this, thanks for your time.